# CryptoUtils.DLL - functions 'EncryptFileUsingSymmetricKey' and 'DecryptFileUsingSymmetricKey'

Tags: cryptography

Has anyone used `CryptoUtils.DLL`? Is there any documentation available for the same and can someone point me to it?

I am interested in using the functions `EncryptFileUsingSymmetricKey` and `DecryptFileUsingSymmetricKey`. I had opened this DLL in IDA Pro Free and have observed that both of these functions use `7` parameters. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with the same.

Comment: And where from does this DLL come?

Comment: Sorry for the late response to your question. But, after careful analysis it seems that it was a part of the application developed earlier and is not a Microsoft DLL (as we had thought earlier). We have been able to find a workaround to this problem. Thanks a lot.